# Tabbing from field to field doesn't work (aka "tab order" in Java SWT)

Tags: java, forms, swt, tabbing

I have a Java SWT desktop application with various pages etc. pp. It works perfectly well, except the tab order - not at all. When I am in "field 1" and press Tab on my keyboard, I want the application to jump to "field 2", so I don't have to click to the second field after I entered the information in the first one.

Generally there is the "setTabList", where you can set the right order for "tabbing through the form". My problem is I don't even need to set the order right, tabbing doesn't work at all.

When I am in a field of my form and press Tab, for a millisecond I can see the Windows "working circle" (or whatever it is called) and nothing happens. The cursor stays exactly at the same position. It won't jump to another field and I have no idea why.

Generally my code:

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
  Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
  setControl(container);

  fieldOne = new StyledText(container, SWT.NONE);
  fieldOne.setBounds(whatever);
  fieldOne.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
      txtChanged();
    }
  });

  fieldTwo = new StyledText(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
  fieldOne.setBounds(whatever);
  fieldOne.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
      txtChanged();
    }
  });

  Control[] controls = { fieldOne, fieldTwo };
  container.setTabList(controls);
}
```

Even if I leave the Control[] and container.setTabList rows out, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In a `StyledText` control <kbd>Tab</kbd> normally just moves the cursor to the next tab stop inside the control. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> moves to the next control.

You can override this with a traverse listener:

```
fieldOne.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
  @Override
  public void keyTraversed(final TraverseEvent e) {
    if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT || e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS) {
      e.doit = true;
    }
  }
});
```

It is also possible that your key listener is interfering with normal operation. Use a `ModifyListener` if all you want to know is that the text has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What happened: Neither Tab nor Ctrl + Tab worked. Your second guess was right. With the KeyListener it listens to every Key. So if you press Tab it will fall into txtChanged();, because Tab is a key and therefore this is what it does. So this is solved with the ModifyListener and the "Windows working circle" does not longer appear. 

Still: Nothing happens. Neither with Tab, nor with Ctrl + Tab. Any more guesses?

Comment: Works fine for me testing here so you need to provide an [mcve] so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: I really want to, but the application isn't that small, grew over years with multiple people etc. p. - you get my point. Nevertheless I found out why it doesn't work: This composite is in an extra window and (I have no idea why) the main shell window is something else. I found out that another person hid the shell window with "shell.setSize(0, 0)" because this main shell window isn't used and so it is hidden. What happens when you do this is that the tabbing doesn't work. Even with (1, 1) it works again. Workaround: Find a way to hide it without setting the size to 0. (have to find out how)

Comment: Additional update: This window existed because of "shell.setLocation(x, y)". This created a little gray window in the middle of my monitor. Commenting this out as well - everything works fine.